# SAP HYBRIS - split backoffice-config.xml into several xml

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Currently working on an SAP Hybris Application, I was wondering if it is possible to split the `*-backoffice-config.xml` into several smaller xml files ?

Comment: Is normal `<import resource="child-backoffice-config.xml"/>` not working?

Comment: You can create multiple backoffice extensions. Does that help?

Comment: @HybrisHelp: Not, it doesn't work. I already tried. 

@Johannes Nolte: The `*-backoffice-config.xml` I want to split is already inside a new extension. Creating a new one is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from the experts.hybris forum:

" ***Unfortunately there is no way of having `*-backoffice-config.xml` file divided into smaller chunks***. Still there is a good news - `*-backoffice-widgets.xml` file supports a tag called import which gives possibility to separate different logic/parts of mesh-up in different files. " - Jacek Wawrzynek

Source: 
https://experts.hybris.com/questions/100092/split-backoffice-configxml-into-several-smaller-xm.html

Comment: Edit your answer with how you have used `Import` tag. It would help others!!